# Looking for a 3D animation showing the motion of the sun relative to other stars and the Milky Way, any one seen anything like that?

Tags: the-sun

I am looking for an animation that not only shows the inclination of the solar system respective to the plane of the galaxy, but also shows the motion of the sun relative to and in conjunction with (i.e keeping the local frame of reference of rest intact) the local group of stars. If anyone has seen such a animation or if anyone has the skill set to make this animation then it would be a great help!

Comment: The point is unless you use a schematic representation you see nothing. If visual helpers such as vectors and grids are ok than something like https://celestia.space can perhaps do it

Comment: This is not exactly what you're looking for, but nevertheless amazing. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T_qMdaqQB_c